# xcode - Load UIWebView from local html file

Tags: ios, xcode, uiwebview

i am new to ios so excuse me if i write something wrong 
First as appear in .m file i read file and append some code its work fine 
and display data as expected except in one ,

it convert html tags to (& lt ;) but without space

this make my web view 
why that happen

**.h file**

```
@interface FullReport : UIViewController<UIWebViewDelegate >
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *web;
```

**.m file**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
     //read FilePath
     NSString * myPath= [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"content" ofType:@"txt"];
    // read file content html code 
        NSString *fileContent = [[NSString alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:myPath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
    // append some code to it 
        fileContent = [fileContent stringByAppendingString:reportBody];
        NSLog(@"content file %@",fileContent);
    // laod it into my UIWebView 
        [web loadHTMLString:fileContent baseURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:myPath]];

    [super viewDidLoad];

}
```

[image] [image]

Comment: Please check for wrong opening or missing tags like <body> and <html>

Comment: i have this project in android , and its work there fine , we get from same source , so i think that is not the problem

Answer (score 1):

```
[webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:<filepath>]]];
```

here filepath is the path of the file content stored.